# using console.log as a promise callback

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

I found it bit strange that, resolving a promise like this

```
.then(console.log, console.log)
```

doesn't work, but this works

```
 .then(d => {
     console.log(d);
   }, err => {
     console.log(err);
   });
```

what am I missing

Comment: The `log` function needs the `console` context - you lose the proper `this` reference in the first code.

Comment: thanks.. what should I do close this qn? or delete?

Comment: Well maybe with a more specific title (like, "Weird problem using console.log as a promise callback" or something) it might be useful, and you or I can type in a brief answer.

Comment: please write it as an answer, I will accept it then. thanks again for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `console.log()` function needs the `console` object as the value of `this`, or else it won't/can't work. You achieve that with the second bit of code because you're calling `console.log()` as one normally would. In the first code, however, you're "stripping" the reference to the function away from the object itself, so when the promise mechanism makes the function call it has no way of knowing that it should arrange for `this` to be the `console` object.

You could also do

```
.then(console.log.bind(console), console.log.bind(console))
```

though that's pretty ugly :)